# Function stuck while splitting a list of nodes in two lists, but only when the splitted lists contains more than one element

Tags: c, list, split, nodes

The function `split` takes as parameter one `list` variable, which is a just a pointer to a `node` element, with its `int val` and `node * next` variables; that function should return an array of two lists, one for even numbers, and one for odd numbers.
I'm just returning a `void` at the moment, just because my first goal is to make the `split` function to do what it's supposed to do, then I'll just return the result (was thinking of returning an array of structs).

The trouble is, the function `split` looks stuck when `my_list` contains at least two even or two odd numbers (which means will always be stuck when it does contains at least three nodes).

As soon as I'm inserting a maximum of two nodes (one even, and one odd numbers), the function works as expected, while when `my_list` contains at least two even numbers or two odd numbers, the console just looks stuck: it doesn't even print the first `printf` command of the function, and every digit I put on the stdin just do nothing anymore; I don't receive any segmentation fault error.

**The issue does not show up** when I comment the two lines `list_even = insert(list_even, n1)` and `list_odd = insert(list_odd, n1)`: why is that, how to solve it, and why it doesn't happen when `my_list` contains one even number and one odd number? I'm using exactly in the same way the insert method that I've used in the `list.c` file.

It looks like `list_even` and `list_odd` cannot contains more than one element each, or the function get stuck, but why?

***LIST.C***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "list.h"
void help();

int main(){
   list my_list = L_EMPTYLIST;
   help();
   
   ...
   
   while(chose!=0){
      switch(chose){
         case 1:
            puts("Insert an int.");
            getchar();
            int item = 0;
            scanf("%d", &item);
            
            node *my_node = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
            my_node->val = item;
            my_node->next = NULL;
            
            my_list = insert(my_list, my_node);
            break;
         case 2:
            print(my_list);
            break;
         case 3:
            split(my_list);
            break;
         case 4:
            my_list = clear(my_list);
            break;
      }
      
      ...

   }
   
}

void help(){
   puts("1: Insert node.");
   puts("2: Print the list.");
   puts("3: Split the list.");
   puts("4: Clear the list.");
   puts("0: Exit.");
}
```

***LIST.H***

```
// Definitions of the structures
typedef struct _node node;
typedef node *list;

struct _node{
   int val;
   struct _node *next;
};

struct _node nodes[2]; //Not used yet

#define L_EMPTYLIST NULL

// Operations on the list above
list insert(list my_list, node* my_node){
   if(my_list==L_EMPTYLIST){
      //List is empty
      my_list = my_node;
   } else {
      node *head = my_list;
      while(head->next!=NULL){
         head = head->next;
      }
      head->next = my_node;
   }
   return my_list;
}

void split(list my_list){
   printf("hello"); // THIS NOT EVEN PRINTED WHEN my_list contains two even numbers or two odd numbers (?)
   list list_even = L_EMPTYLIST;
   list list_odd = L_EMPTYLIST;
   
   if(my_list==L_EMPTYLIST){
      puts("List is empty: cannot split.");
   } else {
     node *n1 = my_list;
     while(n1!=NULL){
        if((n1->val)%2==0){
           //n pari
           list_even = insert(list_even, n1); //This cause the issue
        } else {
           list_odd = insert(list_odd, n1); //This cause the issue
        }
        n1=n1->next;
     }
     print(list_even);
     print(list_odd);
   }
}

void print(list my_list){...}
list clear(list my_list){...}
```

Comment: My advice would be to make this a [mcve] with some hardcoded data that demonstrates the problem. You should also consider stepping through the code in a debugger to see what's going on. It seems like you probably have an infinite loop somewhere and that should be easy to see when debugging.

Comment: Think about what it means to insert a node in a new list when it is already a member of another list. Where should `next` point? Do you need to make a copy of the node for the new list?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I was stuck from 2 days and with your comment I solved in 5 mins, thanks you! I'm going to post the code, I think I got the problem! When I was doing `list_even = insert(list_even, n1)`, I was adding the node with the previous `next` included, which means I'm adding the whole `list` in `list_even` and `list_odd`. Then, the `head->next = my_node' line` in the `insert`, just make me to lose the `NULL` in the latest next of the list = infinite loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks the problem was adding directly the node `n1` to `list_even` and `list_odd`, just because `node *n1 = my_list`, which means I'm not only adding the single even or the odd node, but also its `next` values: in practice I'm appending the whole `list` in `list_even` and `list_odd`, starting respectively from its first even and odd nodes.

Then,in the `insert` function I'm reaching the end of `list_even` and `list_odd`, but I'm replacing its `NULL` value in the `next` with the second even or odd value: once the `NULL` value is overwritten, I can't get out from the `insert` function.

I basically obtain something like this:

> list: (5)->(10)->(15)->(20)->(25)->(30)->NULL

> list_even (first step): (10)->(15)->(20)->(25)->(30)->NULL

> list_even (second step): (10)->(15)->(20)->(25)->(30)->(20)->(25)->(30)

**Fixed `split` function:**

```
void split(list my_list){
   printf("ciao");
   list list_even = L_EMPTYLIST;
   list list_odd = L_EMPTYLIST;
   
   if(my_list==L_EMPTYLIST){
      puts("List is empty: cannot split.");
   } else {
     node *n1 = my_list;
     while(n1!=NULL){
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
        new_node->val = n1->val;
        new_node->next = NULL; // THE PROBLEM WAS FORGETTING THIS
        if((n1->val)%2==0){
           //n pari
           list_even = insert(list_even, new_node);
        } else {
           list_odd = insert(list_odd, new_node);
        }
        n1=n1->next;
     }
     print(list_even);
     print(list_odd);
   }
}
```

Comment: You might consider adding a function to allocate nodes to avoid repeating yourself. Like `node* new_node(int value);` Makes things cleaner. https://godbolt.org/z/56vEYbPzM